# Page not found when launching Genie app in Julia

Tags: julia, genie.jl

In R we may use Shiny and in python we could use Streamlit. It seems that in Julia we could use the `Genie` framework to create web applications. When I am trying to run a simple app, the app doesn't work with `up()`. I have the following script called `app.jl`:

```
using Genie
route("/hello") do
    "Welcome to Genie!"
end
```

First we load the app:

```
Genie.loadapp()
```

Output:

```
 ██████╗ ███████╗███╗   ██╗██╗███████╗    ███████╗
██╔════╝ ██╔════╝████╗  ██║██║██╔════╝    ██╔════╝
██║  ███╗█████╗  ██╔██╗ ██║██║█████╗      ███████╗
██║   ██║██╔══╝  ██║╚██╗██║██║██╔══╝      ╚════██║
╚██████╔╝███████╗██║ ╚████║██║███████╗    ███████║
 ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚═╝╚══════╝    ╚══════╝

| Website  https://genieframework.com
| GitHub   https://github.com/genieframework
| Docs     https://genieframework.com/docs
| Discord  https://discord.com/invite/9zyZbD6J7H
| Twitter  https://twitter.com/essenciary

Active env: DEV


Ready!
```

Now start the server:

```
up()
┌ Info: 
└ Web Server starting at http://127.0.0.1:8000 
Genie.Server.ServersCollection(Task (failed) @0x00000001471f6770, nothing)
```

Using the url we get an error saying page not found. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to launch an app with Genie in Julia?

Comment: They have a comprehensive set of tutorials on their [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/@genieframework). Checking it would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the port number is already in use which is a standard situation if you run `up()` more than once.

```
julia> up()
┌ Info:
└ Web Server starting at http://127.0.0.1:8000
Genie.Server.ServersCollection(Task (runnable) @0x0000012f0ab07a30, nothing)

julia> up()
┌ Info:
└ Web Server starting at http://127.0.0.1:8000
Genie.Server.ServersCollection(Task (failed) @0x0000012f0bc68010, nothing)
```

The error message is not shown in the console but it is available in the object returned by up(). Simply get it into variable (or use the special `ans` variable having the last REPL result) and peek at the content of `wevserver` field

```
julia> status = up()
┌ Info:
└ Web Server starting at http://127.0.0.1:8000
Genie.Server.ServersCollection(Task (failed) @0x0000012ec0c2eca0, nothing)

julia> status.webserver
Task (failed) @0x0000012ec0c2eca0
IOError: listen: address already in use (EADDRINUSE)
Stacktrace:
...
```